# Incorrect datetime value: '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' for column 'call_time' at row 1 in Mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a column named `call_time` in my table which is of datatype `DATETIME` in mysql.Now i am trying to insert `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` in to the call_time colum but is is giving following error..

```
Incorrect datetime value: '1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM' for column 'call_time' at row 1
```

Here is my complete query string ..

```
insert into outcall values('0117','509','02240576000','','1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM','07:1','7')
```

Please help me ..

Comment: Have you tried `0001-01-01 00:00:00` ?

Comment: @BartFriederichs this is executing..what can i do to insert into my format that is mentioned

Comment: use `STR_TO_DATE`; see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To insert dates and times, you have to use the ISO date format:

```
insert into outcall values('0117','509','02240576000','','0001-01-01 00:00:00','07:1','7')
```

if you want to use another format, use [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function:

```
STR_TO_DATE("1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM", "%c/%e/%Y %r")
```

Comment: mysql accept a bunch of non ISO format. This is a range issue, here.

Comment: @artragis no it isn't. I tried and it inserts fine. MySQL 5.5.35

Answer (score 1):

Per MySQL documention at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

> The DATETIME type ... supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

The only value allowed outside this range is the value `0000-00-00 00:00:00`

Your value, `1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM` is outside this range

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting date that is not supporetd by mysql,`DATETIME` datatype  supported range is `1000-01-01 00:00:00` to `9999-12-31 23:59:59`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html) :

> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

That means you just try to insert a too early date inside your database. Try

```
insert into outcall values('0117','509','02240576000','','1000-01-01 12:00:00 AM','07:1','7')
```

Comment: That's strange. My MySQL 5.5.35 accepts the date just fine.